# Math objects not displaying in VS Code with Jupyter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, latex

I am trying to write mathematical equations in a Jupyter Notebook in VS Code. When I try to run the code, it just doesn't display anything. What might be the possible cause for this?

This is my code:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex
display(Math('a^2 + b^2 = c^2'))
```

Image below:

[image: 1]

Comment: Have your question been solved? I tried the code and it works fine

Comment: It's still not working. I think I should install VS Code afresh. Hope that will do it!

Comment: When I try to run it, the following message flashes. '${file}' can not be resolved. Please open an editor.